# Minecraft map keep saved file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I download a minecraft map and played for quite a while but the map is being updated so I was wondering if it would be possible to keep my current saved file while playing in the updated version. Otherwise I'd have to start all over.. :(

Comment: That depends entirely on the map. Your progress could be placed blocks and the new version could have blocks in different places. You should ask the map maker or just keep playing on the old version.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just take out the old version from the saves folder (.minecraft/saves) and place it somewhere else. Now you can download the new version, place it in the saves folder and play it.

Comment: I think OP is asking to rebase their changes onto the updated map.